# Matlab reading and plotting text file data from notepad,

Tags: matlab, text, text-files, notepad

I am trying to get the my data read through Matlab and then plot it, but with my code using fscanf and/or textscan the file is being read as one array and taking the data one by one as a character which makes it impossible to plot. It's like each char/integer is an array. Here's how my data looks like:

```
Time        Volt     Chan 1  chan 2   chan 3    chan 4   chan 5     chan 6   chan 7
3333.222        222.33   0.2334  0.3444   0.2233    0.4455   -0.733     0.3333   0.12345
3333.222        0.2323   0.4566  0.3456   0.2453    0.4563   -0.753     0.2356   0.23455
```

I want to plot the time data Versus the volts and the other channels separately. Can Anyone help? I know the data looks wrong on here but there's two set of data for each channels.

Comment: is the txt file formatted in the way you reported? or in a standard tabular way with any variable as header and the associated values as attributes?

Comment: Why don't you update your question with a screen shot of input data sets and expected (manual) output. That would really help and call me visual :D

Answer (score 0):

it seems like that apart from the first row, the rest of the file is quite ordered.
Try read the first line using `fgetl`, and then the rest of the lines using `textscan`
Something like:

```
fid = fopen( filename );
firstLine = fgetl( fid );
C = textscan( fid, '%f', 9 );
volt = [];
tm = [];
ch = zeros(0, 7);
while ~isempty(C{1})        
    volt( end + 1 ) = C{1}(1);
    tm( end + 1 ) = C{1}(2);
    ch( end + 1, : ) = C{1}(3:end)';
    C = textscan( fid, '%f', 9 );
end
figure;
plot( tm , volt ); title('volt vs time');
figure;
plot( tm, ch ); legend({'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', c7'});
title('chnnels vs time');
```